# PHP Session variable - find time difference

Tags: php, date, session, time

The program I am trying to write is simple enough, find the difference between two times: today's, and the time the user logs in which is put in a session variable.

The session variable

```
$_SESSION['loginTime'];
```

is set to today's date

```
$_SESSION['loginTime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

When the user logs out the duration they have been logged in is found using this code on a separate page:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loginTime']))
{
    $logTime = $_SESSION['loginTime'];

    $duration = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - strtotime($logTime);
    $duration = date('H:i:s', $duration);

}
```

If I were to log in now (22:15 19/04/2016) and stay logged in for 1min 10 sec it returns **01:01:10**. I cannot understand where the extra hour is coming from, all timezones are set the same.

- The minutes and seconds are calculated fine but 1 hour is added for seemingly no reason

Thanks for reading! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the unix timestamp value of `$duration` before you run the `date` function on it?

Comment: @Martin Thanks for answering! Are you aware of any way to account for the daylight saving?

Comment: there's [gmdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) *if* it is a daylight saving issue

Comment: It would be better to save (another) session variable as the unix timestamp so you don't get these issues "lost in conversion" .

Comment: @Martin thank you the gmdate has seemed to fix it! Thank you for the advice I will try to adapt the unix timestamp in somehow. Again many thanks!

Comment: that strtotime stuff is highly redundant. generate a timestamp, format it into a string, then parse that string BACK into a timestamp? Utterly pointless. you just want a difference in seconds, so `$_SESSION['logintime'] = time();`, and then `$duration = time() - $_SESSION['logintime']`. and note that you CAN'T use `date()` to format an interval.  date expects a proper timestamp. it'll munge intervals easily. e.g. if your interval is 1.2 days, `h:i:s` will print only the hour/minute/seconds, and drop the day, because you didn't tell it to print that.

Comment: What php version are you using?

Comment: what daylight savings issue are you talking about? you mean you want to give a difference between hours of the two days? using an epoch based timestamp and simply subtracting one from the other will give you a seconds (or split-seconds) value that can be turned into minutes/hours/days. If DST is involved, say they last logged in Saturday 10PM and log in again Sunday 4AM, then "6 hours" is the wrong answer, because it was really either 5 (in spring) or 7 (in fall).

Answer (score 4):

The DateTime object is your friend.

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php), a simple example is as follows:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

You can easily adapt your code to something like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loginTime']))
{
    $logTime = new \DateTime($_SESSION['loginTime']);
    $currentTime = new \DateTime('now');
    $interval = $logTime->diff($currentTime);
    $duration = $interval->format('%H:%i:%s');
}
echo $duration;
```

---

Example output:

> 15:48:57

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to DST. It is related to timezones in general. The difference between `$logTime` and `now()` is usually small, like minutes in the OP. For `date` that results in a time on January 1st, 1970. But 00:00 GMT is 01:00 in most European mainland cities.

The quick fix would be to use `gmdate()` instead of `date()` to convert the difference from seconds back into H:i:s format. The proper solution is to use `DateTime` objects and the `diff` function to get a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), as David Wyly suggested.